# Why does a one line txt file take longer to open?

Tags: objective-c, macos, text-files, nstextview

I have downloaded a book from project gutenberg that is about 3 mbs in size and I am annoyed with all line breaks and whitespace in the file so I used the following code on the content string of the txt file:

```
[[txtFileContentString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Later on I use the nsstring method writeToFile to write the string to a file.
Now everything is fine but the file takes 2-3 seconds to open while before the it opened instantaneously. I do not know mush about working with txt files but I guess it has something to do with the this new file having one line... Both files are encoded in utf8. So I am wondering why does it take longer to load the txt file and is there another way to do this?

(The reason I want to get rid of the line breaks is that when I load the txt file contents into my nstextview I get awful line breaks in middle of my lines, because my nstextview has another width than that set for the project gutenberg file)